# Point Guard Problem Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am currently taking calculus course and is in derivative section. I have this problem i currently am struggling a lot on how to solve...

> A point guard for an NBA team averages 15 free-throw opportunities per
>   game. He currently hits 72% of his free throws. As he improves, the
>   number of free-throws opportunities decreases by 1 free throw per
>   game. and his percentage of free throws made increases by 0.5
>   percentage point per game. When his decreasing free throws and
>   increasing percentage are taken into account, what is the rate of
>   change in the number of free-throw points that this point guard makes
>   per game?

What does it mean when it says `what is the rate of change in the number of free throw point guard makes per game` ?

Comment: Probably the same as your last question: define a function of number of free-throws dependent on the games and evaluate the derivative at 0.

Comment: @VladimirVargas ok so.. Basically i did this $f(n)= 15 - (n-1)$ , since it says it decreases 1 after each game and it started with 15 free throw opportunities. Now i find the derivative of that which is $f'(n)=1$ .. So you plug in 0 , and it becomes 1? Or am i not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Be careful with how you write $f$. For instance, you are saying that the number of free-throw opps per game is currently $f(0) = 15-(0-1) = 16$, which is false.

Comment: @VladimirVargas Sorry i meant $f(n)= 15 + (n-1)$

Comment: amanuel, you run into the same problem. The game 0 gives  $f(0)=14$, which is false. The correct function is $f(n) = 15 - n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of free throws the guard makes a game is going to be your $f(x)$ so the rate of change will be the derivative or $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Now you just need to figure out what the $f(x)$ is:

number of free throws made per game = number of free throws taken * percentage made

or $$f(x) = (15 - x)(.72+.005x)$$ with x being the number of games so far. Simplify that $$f(x) = 10.8-.645x-.005x^2$$ $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-.01x-.645$$ Thats the rate of change and if they ask for a specific game just plug that in for x

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! .. Any ideas how you got `free throws made per game = number of free throws taken * percentage made` ?

Comment: @amanuel2 the percentage is just how often he makes it. You can think of it as a fraction $\frac{72 (made shots}{100 (attempted shots)}$ when you multiply that by how many shots attempts he does, you get how many free throws he makes

Comment: zamsler : ahh okay. Well seems like i understand now.. Idk which answer to accept

Answer (score 3):

$$ft(g) = 15 - g,$$

tells you the number of $ft$, free-throw opportunities per game, as a function of games played $g$. So, with no games we get the 15 free-throw opps per game.

He makes 72% of the free throws, so that the points made by the guard per game are:

$$ p(ft, g) = ft\times (0.72 + 0.05g) = (15-g)(0.72 + 0.005g) $$

This is the function you have to derivate.

Comment: Your $p(fg,t)$ always throws me off like last question :-(

Comment: @amanuel2 It just means that the points depend on the free-throws, and also on the number of games. However, the free-throws depend only on the number of games as well.

Comment: @amanuel2, toss a coin, but don't leave it without accepted answer, it helps other people.

Comment: Ok tossed coins three times... zamsler got it with 2 wins. Sorry :-( . Ill upvote your answer though :-)